# Is this bad RAII design?

Tags: c++, constructor, raii

I come from a Java background, but I learned C++ after and have been programming with it for a few years now (mostly debugging and writing fixes, not designing programs from scratch). However, I ran into an issue today and frankly, I'm a little surprised it took this long to come across it.

Let's say I have a class named Class1 whose header file contains (among other code):

```
class Class1 {
    private:
        Class2 object;
}
```

The Class2 class doesn't have a default constructor specified. Now, in the Class1 constructor, I'm reading the binary header of a file and using the info I parse from that to initialize Class2, as shown with the pseudo-code below:

```
Class1::Class1(std::string) {
    // Read some binary info from a file here

    // Parse that binary info

    object2 = Class2(info);
```

In Java, since it's not using the RAII paradigm, that would be perfectly legal. However, since C++ uses RAII, object 2 was already initialized with its default constructor by the time I do `object2 = Class2(info);`. I couldn't have just called that constructor originally (in the Class1 header file) because I didn't have the info I needed to create `object` yet. However, I can't just make `object2` local to the constructor, because I need other functions to be able to see/use it.

Clearly this doesn't work. What's the standard approach for this stuff? I actually thought about just changing Class1 to having a Class2 pointer like so:

```
class Class1 {
    private:
        Class2* objectPointer;
}
```

and then calling `*objectPointer = Class2(info)`. However, "Class2" in my case is an ifstream and it seems that the `operator=` function has been deleted and doesn't work with either approach.

So... how do I do this?

Comment: lol! 4 identical answers within < 1 min

Comment: I don't think it's quite right to say that "C++ uses RAII". C++ enables RAII, but doesn't require its use.

Comment: Note that RAII is a horrible name for a wonderful feature. While the name hints at initialization, the important side is destruction: every resource should be managed by a class. It has nothing for/against 2 phase initialization (although you may want to avoid it whenever possible)

Comment: @RobK Yeah, I probably should have worded my question a bit more carefully... something along the lines of "However, since C++ allows for RAII and it's generally good practice," or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because your `object` is not `const`, that's all perfectly legal. However, if you want to initialise `objects` in the initialisation phase, you must provide the information. You can do that such

```
 Class1::Class1(std::string file_name) : object(InfoFromFile(file_name)) {}
```

where `InfoFromFile()` would either be a standalone function (declared in an anonymous namespace within a .cc file) or a static member function of `Class1`. If more information than file_name is required to generate the information needed for `Class2`, you can provide it to that function.

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten that a huge point of using initialization lists was to choose which constructor is called for that member instead of the default. I added `object` to the list like you mentioned and sure enough, all is well now.

Answer (score 5):

If the "read and parse" part doesn't require the object to have been constructed, then you could move that to a static (or non-member) function, and the initialise the member using the result of that:

```
Class1::Class1(std::string) :
    object2(read_class2_info(some_file))
{}
```

If you really can't separate the file reading from the object construction for some reason, and can't reassign `object2` later, then you will need to use a pointer. To create the object, you'd use `new`:

```
objectPointer = new Class2(info);
```

However, to save yourself from having to mess around the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722), you should avoid managing dynamic objects yourself, and instead use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Class2> objectPointer;

objectPointer.reset(new Class2(info));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a local function to do the bits that read the binary info and directly initialize in the constructor list:

```
namespace {

InfoObject readInfo(std::string s)
{
// Read some binary info from a file here

// Parse that binary info
  return info;
}

}

Class1::Class1(std::string s)
: object(readInfo(s))
{
}
```

Using a pointer is, of course, also an option. This is also why this works more naturally in Java (every user type is a pointer, internally). You probably want to use a smart-pointer though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to initialize `object` with dummy data, and then update it with the new data once you've parsed it.

Something like this:

```
Class1(std::string str)
 : object("some valid-but-meaningless data")
{
    // parse info
    object = Class2(info);
```

If this is no good, you probably have to do the parsing in a static factor method that then passes info to the constructor (which you might very well make private). Something like this:

```
Class1(Info info)
 : object(info)
{
    // whatever else you want
}

static Class1 create(std::string)
{
    // parse info
    return Class1(info);
}
```

EDIT: I actually like Walter's answer better; using a function in the initialization is a good idea. I'm just leaving this here for some alternate ideas you can consider.